# Series capacitor balancing in RC filter

Tags: capacitor, filter, remote-control, series

I am trying to make a 600v RC filter with a cutoff frequency of 1hz or less.
The problem is the capacitor prices for these voltages are too high.

I want to use series capacitors to up the voltage rating and lower the cost but I have a few questions.

For starters how do I determine resistor value for the leak resistors?
Does leak resistor balancing mean I can use differently rated capacitors?
Also, how does this configuration affect the filter itself?

[image]

Comment: That's not the normal way to achieve DC smoothing after a rectifier.

Comment: Welcome to SE. Thank you for the schematic - it's a big help. If you add in some detail about what you're trying to make we may be able to give more relevant answers. There's also a schematic button on the editor toolbar, should you require it.

Comment: It's an RC filter with two 500uf capacitors and a 300ohm resistor. It's a 600v supply so unless I want to spend lots of money I need to use the capacitors in series but I have to balance them with leak resistors or else one capacitor could end up having greater leakage than the other and the voltage rating will be exceeded. I'm not sure how the resistor divider affects the filter though nor am I sure how to calculate the resistor value.

Comment: I'm thinking you might want to use a different capacitance or 'leak' resistance one one of your two capacitive 'legs' to ground. By my understanding, placing the leak resistors in parallel with the capacitors creates a resonant tank circuit, or a band-stop filter between your Vpos and ground. Then placing 2 such identical tanks in series effectively may be making that a second order filter. I don't see much way around that for one 'leg,' but at least using a different value resistance for the other 'leg' could make it resonate at a different frequency, rather than enhancing the effect.

Comment: As for resistor sizing, as long as you make sure the legs aren't tuned to harmonics of each other, I think you'll find you can have a pretty wide tolerance there (unless you're looking tomachieve a very specific freq at somewhere <1cycle/sec). Just keel in mind the amount of current flowing through them for resistor power ratings, and your power losses through them.

Comment: But the resistors neither create a highpass nor a lowpass filter right? Don't you need both for a band-stop filter?

Comment: You should seriously consider replacing the series R with a coil. You get second-order filtering, and you can cut the capacitance after the coil too.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. For a cutoff frequency of 1 Hz, you need a time constant of 159 ms. Given your 1 kΩ load resistance, this means that you need at least 159 µF of capacitance.

In order to determine the maximum value of the the bleed (leak) resistors, you need to find out what the maximum leakage current of the capacitors is. Then, in order to keep the voltage variation across the capacitors to within, say, 10% of the nominal value (300 V ±30 V), you want the current through the resistors to be about 10× the worst-case leakage current through the capacitors.

For example, suppose the maximum leakage current is 10 µA. That means you want 100 µA flowing through the resistors. At 300 V, this requires a resistance of no more than 300 V / 100 µA = 3 MΩ each.

If the capacitor leakage is given in terms of an "equivalent parallel resistance" value, then just pick a bleed resistor that is no more than 1/10 of that value.

Pay attention to the power dissipation of those resistors. At 300 V, a 3-MΩ resistor will dissipate (300 V)<sup>2</sup> / 3 MΩ = 30 mW. A 1-MΩ resistor will dissipate 90 mW.

Resistors (especially SMDs) also have a maximum voltage rating. If necessary, use multiple resistors in series so that the voltage across each one is within spec.

---

Now, on a separate issue, you show a 300-Ω series resistor between the two sections of your filter. Your 1-kΩ load is going to be drawing 600 mA, so this means that the 300-Ω resistor is going to be dissipating over 100 W! (0.6 A)<sup>2</sup> × 300 Ω = 108 W.

Actually, the peak voltage from your rectifier is only going to be about 700 V, so if you want the output voltage to be 600 V, you only want to drop 100 V in the filter. Make that resistor 160 Ω — but it will still be dissipating 36 W.

---

> How much overhead voltage do I need for a shunt regulator?

That's a more complicated question than you might think. In fact, it might be worth posting it as a separate question.

A shunt regulator needs to be able to cope with two kinds of variations: changes in the source voltage and changes in the load current. It attempts to control the load voltage by varying its own current consumption in order to control the drop across the source impedance of the power source.

There are four corner cases you need to consider:

```
maximum source voltage   |  maximum source voltage
minimum load current     |  maximum load current
-------------------------+--------------------------
minimum source voltage   |  minimum source voltage
minimum load current     |  maximum load current
```

You need to make sure that the ratings of the series resistor (resistance, power) and the ratings of the regulator itself (current, power) are not exceeded at any of the extremes. For example, a resistance that's low enough to allow the circuit to work in the lower-right corner may cause the regulator current in the upper-left corner to be insanely high.

---

> How do I calculate the cutoff frequency with the above set-up?

Again, with a nonlinear device like a bridge rectifier in the picture, the answer is not straightforward. When the diodes are conducting they have a very low effective source resistance, so the cutoff frequency in that mode will be much higher than whey they're not conducting.

When the diodes are not conducting, the capacitors are simply discharging into the load with a time constant that is determined primarily by the load resistance, which you now say is variable. Actually, if you're using a shunt regulator (another nonlinear device), the load is more properly characterized as a constant-current load, and the capacitor discharge will be a straight line. It doesn't make a whole lot of sense to talk about cutoff frequencies in this kind of circuit, except as a rough approximation. It's usually more interesting to talk about ripple voltages and currents.

Comment: Actually the load resistance will be adjustable so the maximum current will be 100ma but the current draw will be adjustable all the way down to 2ma. I picked a 300 ohm resistor because the RC filter calculator I used gave me a value of 300 minimum for 1hz cutoff but then again the first cap was not factored in. Technically I need over 600v on the output of the filter because I need overhead for a shunt regulator that will come after it.

Comment: 100ma through 300ohms is only 3w and a 30volt drop right? How much overhead voltage do I need for a shunt regulator?

Comment: You raise a good point with the resistor though, the calculations I used to get my results did not include have 2 capacitors. How do I calculate the cutoff frequency with the above set-up?

Comment: Regarding your first comment ... obviously, I can only respond to the information provided in the question. If your actual circuit is more complex, then it's on you to work out the differences. I'll address your other questions by editing my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answers I've taken your advice and opened a new thread for the shunt regulator. I do have another question relating to the series capacitor balancing though. Can I stack more than 2 capacitors in series without issue? Also I've been wondering, when I calculate the leak resistor value do I take the answer as the combined value of all of the resistors in the divider or just each resistor? Thanks.

Comment: Just to add to the above question, is there a point where high esr from series connecting the capacitors becomes an issue?

Comment: Yes, you can stack more than two. I once built an 800-V supply for a ham transceiver that had three stacked up. And with regard to the ESR, as long as each capacitor is working within its specs, stacking them shoiuld cause no additional issues. The bleed resistor calculation above is per capacitor (since the voltage used was per capacitor).